# SpriteKit detect when sprite goes behind another sprite with alpha?

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

The image below shows a black mountain in the foreground with an alpha and a white square representing the "Sun" in the background. If the Sun travels to the right is there anyway in SpriteKit of detecting when it passes behind the peak of the black mountain.

I don't want to hardcode this as the foreground mountain will change as my background scrolls, so I need to do this programatically.

[image]

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can give a `physicsBody` to each sprite and hear for "contact" on the delagate.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14

Comment: Thats certainly an idea, much appreciated Mark.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do as well, just remember to set your zPosition correctly so that the sun goes behind the mountains